# Android JSON receive issue

Tags: java, android

I have a string problem, I used the below code for recieving JSON data from an URL, the code is working fine, but the problem is I am not getting full data only half of the JSON values are coming, I would like to know whether there is reason for this, if so means how to solve this problem. JSON string is very big

```
            DefaultHttpClient http_client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpResponse response = http_client.execute(httpGet);

            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            InputStream in = entity.getContent();
            StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
            byte[] b = new byte[4096];
            int n =  in.read(b);
            while(n>0){
                out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
                n = in.read(b);
            }

            String resultdata = out.toString();
            Log.d("Out data",resultdata);
```

Comment: How do you know that you only get half of the data?

Comment: When I put the URL in web browser it gives full data, when I compare it with Android output, andorid is giving only half of the data (not full like in browser)

Comment: How much big is your json...If your json is too big then you will probably get a OutOfMemoryError

Comment: How do you compare? using what the Log.d("Out data", resultdata) print out?

Comment: Normally, the logcat size is max entry is 4096 bytes per line. So if your resultdata is larger than 4096, it will be cut off.

Answer (score 2):

Try getting data like this using BufferedReader

```
    String line="";
   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                // Read response 
     while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
               total.append(line); 
            }
   String jsonString=total.toString();
```

Comment: @Subramanian  is there any exception in the logcat or any error ?

Comment: @Subramanian Log cat will skip some of the data, if it is too big, are you trying to log your json? And even when you inspect using debugger it will not show full data, If you are trying to do so, then just create a json object , don't worry about your json stirng, it is complete then json object will be created

Comment: @Subramanian Create a json object with the response string, if your json is incomplete then will throw an exception, check once

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26217/discussion-between-pragnani-and-subramanian)

Comment: When I increased the Byte Array it gave complete JSON string, thanks friend for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = out.readLine()) != null) {sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
is.close();
String json = sb.toString();
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove this line

```
int n =  in.read(b);
```

and add

```
  int n=0;

    while ((n= in.read(b)) != null)
```

Comment: It is not the problem with buffer size brother

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
 public static JSONObject getJson(String url){

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    // HTTP
    try {           
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // for port 80 requests!
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

    // Read response to string
    try {           
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();             
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

    // Convert string to object
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);            
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        return null;
    }

    return jsonObject;

}}
```