# Json receiving issue while using OkHttp

Tags: android, json, okhttp

I am using OkHttp for retrieving data from json data from an api. I have written the following code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(forecastUrl).build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                // TODO: manage failure
                // try again
                doInBackground(params);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    nowDataList.clear();
                    hourlyDataList.clear();
                    dailyDataList.clear();
                    try {
                        nowDataList.add(getNowData(jsonData));
                        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
                            hourlyDataList.add(getHourlyData(jsonData, i));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                            dailyDataList.add(getDailyData(jsonData, i));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    // if response is not successful try again
                    doInBackground(params);
                }
            }
```

Now the above code receives full data in good internet speeds (WiFi/LTE).
However I sometimes don't get complete json data on slow internet speed (mostly on 2G/3G)

I have tried the following solution as well: [Android JSON receive issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425674/android-json-receive-issue). Although it is not based on OkHttp, I modified it for my code, but no profit.

Please help me figure out the issue and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onResponse does not wait to get the whole response and if your response is quite big/ or you are not having a good internet connection, then it may be a problem.

I used this and it is working for me.

```
// get the full response
response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

and then continue with your code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For slow connection try to change default timeouts:

```
client.setConnectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
client.setReadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: This did not work. I am able to get response from the api, however sometimes it is not able to get the whole json.

Comment: Maybe the problem is on the server side. There may exists some timeout limit, when server decides to hang up on slow connections. In such situation you get uncompleted data received.

Comment: Could be true. However I am still unconvinced. Will wait for a solution.

Comment: @Moudiz I'll add my answer.